# Listening for changes in a parent model from an AngularJS formatter directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made an AngularJS directive that requires a model and converts the value of the model (which, in this example is "25mm") to something else that is showed in the view (in this example, converted to inches).

Here is a working plnkr demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fO1S9GcubHE57Pf7Kt9G?p=preview

The demo, however, doesn't work as expected. After changing the value of the dropdown from "inches" to "feet", I'd expect the view to be re-rendered with the appropriate value. This is not the case.

I have noticed that this is because I'm not "listening" for changes, and that is why I placed the

```
scope.$watch("[convertFrom, convertTo]", function(n) {

});
```

which works fine in terms of watching for changes, but if I uncomment that `$watch`, the formatter stops working.

My second problem is that I'm pushing functions to the arrays `$formatters` and `$parsers`. To be exact, one function every time the value of the dropdown changes.

My questions are:

- How can I watch for changes and make the formatter work?
- How can I not insert a new function in the `$formatter` and the `$parser` arrays every time my dropdown changes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it myself. Here is a plunkr demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/jgF2QIP4QeA0Glcnn35B?p=preview

It turns out that I need to push my `$parser` and `$formatter` function only once and watch for changes from outside, then trigger a "re-parse" or "re-format":

```
scope.$watch("[convertFrom, convertTo]", function(n) {
    ngModel.$modelValue = '';
});
```